# angularjs : select with different (key, value) not working properly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to load angular "select" with the following code

```
<select class="span11" ng-model="user.countryOfResidence" ng-options="c.option as c.value for c in countries" required>
```

Its loads the data into the select but the default selected value is empty.

my countries array is

```
$scope.countries = [{option:'TL', value:'TIMOR-LESTE'},
{option:'TK', value:'TOKELAU'},
{option:'TJ', value:'TAJIKISTAN'},
{option:'TH', value:'THAILAND'},
{option:'TG', value:'TOGO'},];
```

if i change `'TL'` to `'TIMOR-LESTE'`, (same string for "option" and "value") it works fine. Can any one kindly tell me what is the problem with my code.

user object is

```
$scope.user = {

        countryOfResidence : $scope.countries[0].value

    };
```

Comment: Initialize `$scope.user.countryOfResidence = $scope.countries[0].option` because you are using options as values inside ng-option.

Answer (score 2):

A select populated with ng-options will set the ng-model field to what is specified as the *value*, not the *option*

In the example you've given, you're setting user.countryOfResidence to countries[0].value, which in this case is 'TIMOR-LESTE', but the value key is 'TL', so it won't select it by default.

For better readability, I always like to structure my select options with 'label' and 'value' keys, like so:

```
// Controller

$scope.countries = [
  {value:'TL', label:'TIMOR-LESTE'},
  {value:'TK', label:'TOKELAU'},
  {value:'TJ', label:'TAJIKISTAN'},
  {value:'TH', label:'THAILAND'},
  {value:'TG', label:'TOGO'}
];

$scope.user = {
        countryOfResidence: $scope.countries[0].value
    };
};

// View

<select class="span11" ng-model="user.countryOfResidence" ng-options="c.value as c.label for c in countries" required=""></select>
```